# Combine 2 TextBoxFor bound to one property MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to save the Contact Number in a registration form wherein i'm having 2 TextBox, one for `Country Code` and another for `Number`. Now i need to combine both and bind into a single property which i have in my class. How can i do that?

**View:**

```
 <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Phone, "Contact Number:")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.xxxx,new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtContactCode", required="required", type ="number" })-
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone,new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtContactNumber", required="required", type ="number" })
 </div>
```

Property,

```
 public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Now what should i bind the property in the code of the phone number field to concatenate as one? Is there any way or i should declare another property named `Code` and then proceed?

Comment: Use a view model with properties `CountryCode` and `PhoneNumber` and in the POST method combine the values and map it to your data models `Phone` property

Comment: Show the code which assigns values to your model

Comment: @StephenMuecke Will do the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not try to split/join things. You're just introducing a potential point of failure into your application. If you only care about storing a single combined `Phone`, then let the user enter their phone number directly in a field for `Phone`. If you care about ensuring that every phone number has a country code, you can use a phone number validation library like this [port of Google's libphonenumber library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp), to parse the user entered phone numbers and standardize how they're stored in the database.

The problem with trying to combine two fields into one is that you then have to split that one field back into two. Especially with something like a country code that can be variable length, that's going to be really difficult to do reliably. However, if you insist on going down this path, I'd recommend using a view model like:

```
public string Phone
{
    get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", CountryCode, Number); }
    set
    {
        CountryCode = null;
        Number = null;

        if (value != null)
        {
            var parts = value.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2);
            if (parts.Length == 2)
            {
                CountryCode = parts[0];
                Number = parts[1];
            } 
        }
    }
}

public string CountryCode { get; set; }
public string Number { get; set; }
```

Then, you would bind to `CountryCode` and `Number`, respectively, in your view. The `Phone` custom getter and setter will take care of translating back and forth between combined and constituent parts.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this by using the `BindModel()` method which is available in the `IModelBinder` interface.

> **[IModelBinder.BindModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder.bindmodel(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder.BindModel(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext,System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext)):** Binds the model to a value by using the specified controller context and binding context.

Also see [this explanation with real-time example](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/806415/Model-Binding-using-IModelBinder-and-DefaultModelB).

**Note:** In the above example, `first_name`, `middle_name` and `last_name` were bound to the full name property. You can bind your required two properties to the one property in the same way.